# Return longest word in a sentence

Tags: python

I want to find the longest word in a sentence so that when tested

```
assert longest_word(sentence.split()) == 'sentence'
```

And I have written this

```
def longest_word(sentence):
    individual_words = sentence.split()
    longest_word = len(individual_words[0])
    for i in individual_words:
        word_length = len(i)
        if word_length > longest_word:
            longest_word = word_length
    print(longest_word)
    return(longest_word)
```

It's not working and the error message is "name sentence not defined". Is there not a sentence it checks through?

Comment: Which line does it give the error on?m is it the second one?

Answer (score 1):

When you call the function, you give your 'sentence' parameter a list of words inside your main sentence.

For example:

````
sentence = 'This is a string of words sentence'
sentence.split() will return: ['This', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'of', 'words', 'sentence']

But the first line in your function already splits up your string into individual words, so you're confusing python with which data you're giving it and how```
````

Answer (score 1):

There is a shorter way of doing this.

For example,  in this code, the function `longest_word` splits the sentence into multiple strings (words), from which we find the longest one of them.

```
sentence = 'This is a string of words namely a sentence'
def longest_word(strings):
    return max(strings, key = len)

print(longest_word(sentence.split()))
assert longest_word(sentence.split()) == 'sentence'
```

Output:

```
sentence
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes to your code. First I assigned the word to the `longest_word` and not the length so when you use assert method you don't compare the word 'sentence' with his length. The code below should work :

```
def longest_word(sentence):
    individual_words = sentence.split()
    longest_word = individual_words[0]
    for i in individual_words:
        word_length = len(i)
        if word_length > len(longest_word):
            longest_word = i
    print(longest_word)
    return(longest_word)


sentence='I want to find the longest word in a sentence so that when tested'

assert longest_word(sentence) == 'sentence'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "max":

```
sentence="Find out longest word"
lst=sentence.split(' ')
max(lst, key=len)
```